# Center Google Map in Webview

Tags: c#, google-maps, webview, windows-8.1

I am working on a Windows Universial App. I want to add my map (added some pinpoints using Google MyMaps) in a WebView. I can't manage to center it in the view.

I have done some research and found out that I should use ll for latitude/longitude and it works fine on a browser, but not in the WebView.

XAML code:

```
<WebView x:Name="map"/>
```

C# code:

```
map.Source = new Uri(url + "&z=8" + "&ll=X,Y");
```

X, Y, and url of course have values.
It just seems like it doesn't care and centers the map in another point. Have I missed something?

Comment: Can you provide an example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: I just used an iFrame as an alternative.